# Notations for complex logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, branch-cuts

Are there any specific notations for complex logarithms in different branch cuts? The principal branch is denoted as $\operatorname{Log}z$. But how do I write a logarithm which is sliced on the negative imaginary axis?

Edit: If there are none, how would you write it? Maybe something like $\log_w^{\arg}$? This looks not good in my opinion that's why I need your advice.

Comment: Don't think so.

Comment: I wouldn't invent a notation at all; I would describe the domain of the function clearly in words.

Comment: I can't figure out what the exponent $\arg$ and index $w$ could mean.

Comment: If you need to name the usual branch and this other one in the same text, what about $\log$ and $\log_\perp$ ?

Comment: @GregMartin The problem is that I need two different logarithm branch cuts in one integral.

Comment: Can you split the integral in two parts, neither of which crosses over a branch cut? Then you can use Log in both integrals, and change one of them by hand to $2\pi i + {}$Log.

Comment: Note that "branch cut on negative imaginary axis" technically still doesn't specify which branch you're indicating, since one can add $2\pi i k$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$; however, let's assume we're both thinking about the one that is real on the positive real axis. Then Log $z = \log z$ when $-\frac\pi2<\arg z<\pi$ and Log $z = \log z -2\pi i$ when $-\pi<\arg z<-\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is any widely used notation. However, you can distinguish different branches by specifying the domain of the function. This means that, if the branch you are dealing with has domain $U$, then you can write $\log_U$ or explicitely say that $\log : U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. For instance, the principal branch of $\log$ is obtained by using $U=\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ as domain.